# Check for inclusion of a hash against another hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
arr = [
  { email: 'prathab@hotmail.in', valid: true },
  { email: 'another@mail.com', valid: false }
]
```

I need to check if `email: 'prathab@hotmail.in'` and `valid: true` both exist in a single hash.

How can I check for such hash in the array without using `each` loop?

Currently I am doing this:

```
found = false
arr.each do|v|
  if v[:email] == 'prathab@hotmail.in' && v[:valid] == true
    found = true
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: `'email': 'prathab@hotmail.in'` should be either `'email' => 'prathab@hotmail.in'` or `email: 'prathab@hotmail.in'` otherwise above will throw syntax error.

Comment: that's not true, @ray,  I pasted it and it works. It builds symbols from the strings, you can build a symbol with space inside this way - it's a bit like `:"a text"`

Comment: @mrzasa Yes, you are right, for upper version it works, I was looking ta lower version where it threw syntax error.

Comment: @Pratha Your code is actually wrong. You are looking for wrong keys.

Comment: To be precise, since `:` is not a method, it is not building symbols from the strings, it is a symbol from the beginning.

Comment: @sawa. I've fixed them.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You should be asking the  more general question: "Given a hash `h` and an array of hashes `arr`, how do I determine if all the key-value pairs of `h`  are shared by at least one hash in `arr`?". It's no more difficult to answer the more general question and it will provide you with more robust code that need not be changed in future if `g` or `arr` changes. @sawa has answered the more general question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) that does more or less what you did in your implementation:

```
> found = arr.any?{|e| e[:email] == 'prathab@hotmail.in' && e[:valid] }
=> true
```

Comment: This suffers from the disadvantage that the keys and values are hardwired into the method. Should any change the method would have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 7):

To check if a hash has all the key-value pairs that another hash has, use `>`, `<`, or their variants `>=`, `<=`. You can be assured that the order of key-value pairs does not matter.

```
arr.any?{|h| h >= {email: "prathab@hotmail.in", valid: true}}
# => true

arr.any?{|h| h >= {valid: true, email: "prathab@hotmail.in"}}
# => true
```

Comment: The issue here is inclusion of a hash within another hash.

Comment: Do you have some links for that? Isn't is that slower than direct comparisons?

Comment: How comparison worked on hash? Am I using lower version? ` {} >= {}  => NoMethodError: undefined method `>=' for {}:Hash`

Comment: @mrzasa Please look for Ruby documentation by yourself.

Comment: Works for me ! using `ruby 2.3.1p112` Thanks @sawa

Comment: My bad, it is is real good solution, lower version killed me!

Comment: ...or, given `h`,  `arr.any? { |g| g.merge(h) == g }`, but that's admittedly inferior.

Comment: `g.merge(h) == g` build a new hash on every iteration step, that may hurt performance it it's called frequently or on big arrays